# Is delegate pattern a good approach in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, delegates

I am converting an iOS app from UIKit to SwiftUI. I have a `UIViewController` that displays a view with different buttons. This `UIViewController` has a delegate that conforms to a specific protocol. On each button's action, I call a method of its delegate. Nothing special here, it is a typical Delegate pattern as we all know for iOS development with UIKit.

My question is: Is it still a good approach with SwiftUI? I can totally convert this pattern in my SwiftUI app (I did already. EDIT: and as mentioned in comments, it is NOT a good idea!). But I'm wondering if this Delegate pattern is still a good way or if there is a different way to do that (with Binding maybe?). Is it recommended to use this pattern in a SwiftUI app?

Here is a simplified code example:

```swift
protocol MyCustomViewDelegate {
    func buttonATapped()
}

struct MyCustomView: View {
    public var delegate: MyCustomViewDelegate?
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button A") {
            if let delegate = delegate {
                delegate.buttonATapped()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View, MyCustomViewDelegate {

    var body: some View {
        MyCustomView(delegate: self)
    }

    func buttonATapped() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

EDIT: Please do not use this previous implementation!

Comment: I would definitely *not* recommend using references to SwiftUI views via `self`, passing them to other views. SwiftUI views are transient and you shouldn't rely on a reference like this. You can, however, pass closures back and forth or bindings like you suggested. Your example is a little too vague to suggest something concrete. Perhaps take a look at the Apple or Hacking With Swift SwiftUI tutorials to get a sense of what is common.

Comment: If you use a Delegate you should use it in a `ViewModel` that is an `ObservableObject` not a `View` the delegate methods would update variables that are `@Published` to trigger changes in the `View`

Comment: Thank you for your replies that makes total sense! (I feel stupid having suggested such an implementation!).
I will try different approach. I like the `ViewModel` one but it is a bit too much for my uses I think. Or with closures as hoseinali alborzi's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that if you use closures it is better,
an example to pass the function:

```
 struct MyCustomView: View {
        var function: () -> Void
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.function()
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            ChildView(function: self.buttonATapped)
        }
        
        func buttonATapped() {
            print("I am the parent")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, easy and really usefull. Thank you.
But maybe an implementation with a `ViewModel` would be more "clean". I will have a try.

Comment: A ViewModel represents the state of model data. It facilitates communication between views and models, through bindings, or other events and actions. I think that ViewModel is not for communication two Views

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you. Does that means your solution is the only good implementation of old/previous Delegate pattern from (old/previous) UIKit? I have implemented right now your solution and it works, but it looks to me "not so clean" as with a protocol/delegate, that's why I ask.

Comment: You can use other ways observable , i think that this depend to you that where do you use and between which views  you use

Comment: After a couple of tries, I have implemented your solution in my app. Thanks!